Make a sound when connected to the internet
How can I play a sound when connected to the internet? I found a python script but there should be an simpler solution.
I just want to play a sound upon connection. Even notify-send would work.
I want to know when an internet connection is possible, so I do not start my browser and get a "can not find the webpage.".

In which context? You're usually connected to the internet before your graphical session / tty session is even started. When would you want such sound to play? Should it play just once upon first connection? Or should it play every time you lose connection and reconnect again? Or, maybe, just "on demand" as a "check" to see if you currently have connection?

@kos I just want to sound  upon connection. Even notify-send would work.

Would you be happy with something like a sound playing just once, once you're logged in to your graphical session as your user? Is this on Ubuntu GNOME?

@kos I want to know when an internet connection is possible, so I do not start my browser and get a "can not find the webpage."

I think I would do something like this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..5}; do
    ping -i0.5 -c3 -w3 google.com ||
        {
            sleep 5
            continue
        }

    aplay /path/to/beep.wav
    break
done

The script will check for a "good connection" 5 times, waiting 5 seconds between each check, before giving up.
The definition of "good connection" here is: if we're able to send an ICMP request to google.com and receive an ICMP response 3 times, waiting 0.5 seconds between each request / response and completing the whole cycle within 3 seconds, then we have a "good connection".
If the script detects a "good connection", it will play path/to/beep.wav.
You could put the script in ~/bin/connection_test.sh, run chmod +x ~/bin/connection_test.sh and add it to Startup Applications so that it executes upon logging in to the graphical session.
/path/to/beep.wav must be the full path to the .wav sound to play (to test this I downloaded an mp3 file from https://pixabay.com/it/sound-effects/search/beeps/ and converted it to .wav using ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 beep.wav).
There are also ways to have your PC speaker beep instead, if you happen to have one these days and age.

It is showing file not found. The file is in a root owned folder.

@AndrewK Why is the file in a root-owned folder? Can't you just sudo cp /path/to/file ~/somewhere/in/your/home/directory, chown your_username: ~/somewhere/in/your/home/directory and correct the path to the .wav file in the script?

I made a folder where Ubuntu-Mate has their sound files and put my own sounds. I will move those to my home directory.

@AndrewK If you want to share sounds among users, /usr/share/sounds also would be suitable I think (or ~/.local/share/sounds if they're just for your user)

I am having problems converting an .mp3 to a wav file. VLC is confusing. I am the only user.

@AndrewK ffmpeg -i beep.mp3 beep.wav works for me, have you tried it?

I used audacity.
